# What does a left shift do to a pointer variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, bit-shift

Let's say I have an `unsigned character pointer 'foo'` and that I have **dynamically** assigned the memory for it using **malloc** . What does these operations do to the pointer variable? Let's assume `bar` is called with i values as `2,4,6,8` respectively

```
void bar(int i, unsigned char* foo) {
    *foo++ = i>>24;
    *foo++ = i>>16;
    *foo++ = i>>8;
    *foo++ = i;
}
```

Comment: The shifts are done on `i`, which is not a pointer

Comment: Even if it were grouped `(*foo++ = i)>>24;`, that's a shift on an `char`, not a `char *`

Comment: @Caleth: I think the shifts would be on a temporary of type  `int`, because the `char` is promoted.

Comment: @MSalters yes, overload resolution for `char& >> int` finds `int >> int`, but it has gone through a narrowing conversion to get there from `i`

Comment: And `*(foo++ = i)>>24` is ill-formed, as you are assigning to an rvalue

Comment: @Caleth: Don't know what you're trying to say there, `(foo++ = i)` is already illegal because you assign an integer to a pointer.

Comment: @harold agreed, I misinterpreted the code. and MSalters is correct about the illegal assignment of an Int to a pointer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit shifts are applied to `i`, which is not a pointer, it's a variable of type `int`.

Then, the result is assigned to where the pointer `foo` points to.

Finally, the pointer is incremented by one.

For example, this:

```
*foo++ = i>>24;
```

bit shifts `i` by 24 to the right, then takes that result and assigns it to where `foo` points to. Afterwards, the pointer gets incremented by one.